# grid.table does not show column name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame, that I want to show as a table in my presentation.

I wanted to use grid.table function for this. When I try

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.table(dataframe)
```

I actually get a proper looking table. However, there are no column names. It just starts with the first row. How do I solve this? I already tried to specify the columnnames via

```
library(gridExtra)
colnames(dataframe) <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
grid.table(dataframe)
```

but that doesn't make any difference. Does anyone how to solve this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. Are there lots of rows in your data frame? Does `grid.table(head(dataframe))` show column names? Do they appear if you make your plot window taller?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yeah, there are 26 rows. But they dont appear, if I make the plot window taller. For whatever reason, if I try the ever popular iris petal data frame example, it works perfectly fine

Comment: Is it definitely a data frame? Can you include the output of `dput(dataframe)` in your question so we can replicate?